# Is it possible to have 3 return values in a function php?

Tags: php

I'm wondering if i could return values to a PHP function for example

```
function test()
{
     //returns true or false or a string
}
```

can someone give me an example? I'm new to PHP thank you so much.

Comment: yah return an array of values, but you don't know what an array is right ? :)

Comment: "true or false or a string" implies *one* return value...

Comment: A function ONLY returns ONE and ONLY ONE value.

Comment: You want to return 3 values or either of 3 values??

Comment: buy 3 pairs of shoes at once, get change back once. Buy 3 pairs of shoes at 3 different stores, get change back for each transaction.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, why are you so awesome? :P

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari Because I love a *good* pair of shoes. Hard to find a good pair today; one has to visit many stores to find a "good" pair of shoes ;-) *Ah, shoes!!!* They don't make them like they used to.

Comment: @Marley -- It looks like you are pretty inexperienced at SO. I would recommend taking the tour (you get a badge for your trouble) and become more familiar with the guidelines for posting. This is generally a positive community, but there seems to be litter tolerance for those who do not follow the guidelines.

http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Then follow that up with the help section and read up on the finer points of asking questions.

http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I meant "little tolerance" -- auto-correct is the bane of my existence. I noticed too late to edit.

Comment: Thank you for reminding @manson81.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is a dynamically typed language. This means you are not constrained to return a specific type.

You want to return true, false, or a string. You can do that so long as you only return one of those values. You cannot return all three at the same time unless you make them part of a collection (like an array).

Example:

```
function test() {
    $random = rand(0, 100);

    if (0 == $random) {
        return 'Mark it zero!';
    }

    if (0 == ($random % 10)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this gives the *impression* of returning multiple values using a list.

```
<?php
    function get_multiple()
    {
        return array(10,20,5);
    }

    list($a,$b,$c) = get_multiple();

    echo $a . "<br>";

    echo $b . "<br>";

    echo $c . "<br>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return more then one value, you have two options:

You can return an array:

```
function test()
{
  return array($result1, $result2, $result3);
}
```

Or you can return the results in parameters passed by reference:

```
function test(&$result1, &$result2, &$result3)
{
  $result1 = 10;
  $result2 = 20;
  $result3 = 30;
}

test($r1, $r2, $r3);
echo $r1; // will echo 10;
echo $r2; // will echo 20;
echo $r3; // will echo 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return array:

```
function test(){
  $results[] = $result1;
  $results[] = $result2;
  $results[] = $result3;
return $results
}
```

Or you can declare session variables

```
function test(){
      $_SESSION['result1'] = $result1;
      $_SESSION['result2'] = $result2;
      $_SESSION['result3'] = $result3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your values in an array:

```
function return3values(){
  $value1 = "string";
  $value2 = 2;
  $value3 = "boolean";

  //add your values in an array();
  $array = array();
  $array[0] = $value1;
  $array[1] = $value2;
  $array[2] = $value3;

  return $array;

}

$array = return3values();

echo $array[0];
```

Comment: Should have been a comment instead.

Comment: I must have 50 reputation to comment. Give me some reputation :D

Comment: That's fair, but you could have added more content to your answer, like some example code.

Comment: I am sure you could do better than _you should put your values in an array_ for an answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding content to your answer @sarikaya -- I would recommend editing it to make it look a little more presentable. Also I think the OP said "true or false or a string", but your example contains 2 strings and an int.